# Typescript dynamic generic from string array or object

Tags: typescript

I want to like below:

```
function factory<T>{
      // somethings happen
      return function(args:T){
   }
}


const methodType1 = factory<argType1>();
methodType1({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}); // work
methodType1({d:4}); // not work

const argType2: string[] = ['d'];
const methodType2 = factory<argType2>();
methodType2({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}); // not work
methodType2({d:4}); // work
```

there has something solution? or impossible?

Comment: What is `argType1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a factory method that takes in an array of strings and returns a function that only allows objects with those specific keys:

```
function factory<T extends string>(fields: T[]) {
    // somethings happen
    return function (args: { [P in T]: number }) {
    }
}

const methodType2 = factory(["d"]); // T is 'd'
methodType2({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }); // not work
methodType2({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //error 
methodType2({d:4}); // work
```

If you want not to specify the array directly in the arguments of the function you need to type the constant explicitly as the compiler will not infer string literal types for constant arrays:

```
const argType2 = ['d']; // is string[] which losses information about the keys 
const argType2: Array<'d'> = ['d']; // better, we have the type information now
```

Or you can use a helper function to create the array:

```
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(...fields: T[]) { return fields; }
const argType2 = stringLiteralArray('d') // not explicit types needed is of type Array<'d'>
```

In the function above I typed all keys of the argument as number, if you need more flexibility, you fill need an extra level function that allows us to first specify the type of the keys. (Note in 3.0 we will get the ability to specify only part of the generic arguments, but as of today we are at 2.9 where this is not possible)

```
function factory<T extends string>(fields: T[]) {
    return {
        of<TValue>() {

            return function (args: { [P in T]: TValue }) {
            }
        }
    }
}
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(...fields: T[]) { return fields; }
const argType2 = stringLiteralArray('d') 
const methodType2 = factory(["d"]).of<number>();
methodType2({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }); // not work
methodType2({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //error 
methodType2({d:4}); // work
```

Also as a side note, the function above will raise an error in an object literal with more properties is specified as an argument, but if we put that object literal in a variable and then pass it to the function this is legal.

```
methodType2({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }); //error
let o = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }; 
methodType2(o); // ok
```

If we want to avoid this behavior you can be a bit more restrictive on the generated function:

```
function factory<T extends string>(fields: T[]) {
    return {
        of<TValue>() {

            return function <V extends { [P in T]: number }>(args: V & { [P in Exclude<keyof V, T>]: never}) {
            }
        }
    }
}
function stringLiteralArray<T extends string>(...fields: T[]) { return fields; }
const argType2 = stringLiteralArray('d') 
const methodType2 = factory(["d"]).of<number>();
let o = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }; 
methodType2(o); // error  
methodType2({d:4}); // work
```